# Measure the "aggregate preference" of points on a 2D plane

Tags: statistics, feature-engineering

Consider some points on a 2D plane, we know corrdinates of all
points, how to measure the "aggregate preference" of them.

I don't know what is the exact terminology of
"aggregate preference".

[image]

What I want to express is that,
for example, there are 20 points on a 2D plane,
some time these points are 
distributed uniformly in the space like (1).
We can say that, they have a relatively small "aggregate preference".
Some time, they are distributed more aggregate in space,
form some clusters, like (2).
They have a bigger "aggregate preference" than (1).

Is there are some method(like some statistics or algotithm)
to measure this "aggregate preference"
quantificationally?